# Setting up x-axis and y-axis in MSChart

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I'm using MSChart in ASP.net to render simple column charts. How can I define and show the names of the x-axis and y-axis on the chart?

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the Microsoft Chart Samples Environment and find it yourself.